# Flutter: Firebase current user throws error "Method is called on null"

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to follow an tutorial regarding authentication with firebase. I got a rootPage and there I wanna check if the user is logged in or not. 
Depending on that I will navigate to HomeScreen or LoginScreen.

I'm getting the error "NoSuchMethodError: The Method get current user was called on null" when starting the app.

```
class RootPage extends StatefulWidget {
  RootPage({this.auth});

  final BaseAuth auth;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _RootPageState();
}

class _RootPageState extends State<RootPage> {

AuthStatus authStatus = AuthStatus.NOT_DETERMINED;
String _userID = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.auth.getCurrentUser().then((user) {
      setState(() {
        if (user != null) {
          _userID = user?.uid;
        }
        authStatus =
            user?.uid == null ? AuthStatus.NOT_LOGGED_IN : AuthStatus.LOGGED_IN;
      });
    });
  }
```

The get current user method looks like that

```
Future<FirebaseUser> getCurrentUser() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    return user;
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: make sure you are passing `auth` like  - `RootPage(auth: FirebaseAuth.instance);`

Comment: Can you give an example with code please?

Comment: In your app wherever you are calling `RootPage()` - check are you passing the parameter `auth` as defined by `RootPage()` constructor. like - `RootPage(auth: FirebaseAuth.instance);`

Comment: Ah didn't know I have to do this, thanks! Still learning...

Comment: I don't see why you want to pass `FirebaseAuth.instance` inside a constructor when you can use it wherever you want by calling `FirebaseAuth.instance`.

Answer (score 0):

"NoSuchMethodError method was called on null" errors occurs when you're trying to access a method from a class that has yet to be initialized. Before calling `getCurrentUser()`, check if `auth` has been initialized and add a null-check.